# How to disable Excel number autoformat

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, microsoft-excel-2010

This problem is simple to correct but is very very annoying
what I'm doing is to type a hour range, eg. (0-1),(1-2),(2-3) so on
per cell row

> **DATE** ---   **HOUR** 
>   1/1/2013  0-1
>   1/1/2013  1-2
>  1/1/2013  2-3
>  1/1/2013  3-4

Excel *stupidly* keeps formatting `1-2` to a date `2-Jan`
to make matters worse is when I change it to a number format
it gives `41276`

I also cannot find the AutoFormat option in excel 2010, I am aware of the Format button in home but there is no autoformat there.

Comment: Select cells, right-click on them and change cell format from `General` to `Text`

Comment: Hour range means 1AM -2AM?

Comment: tried changing it to text but it still keeps on insisting the date. And also using military format 1-24 so no am/pm there

Comment: You have to change it to text **before** you enter values. See my answer.

Comment: Simplest way is to type `'1-2` - the `'` tells Excel to treat the entry as text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you enter any values in the column/cells, change the cell format to `Text`.

Or, put this in the Workbook code module to force this formatting on all sheets, each time the workbook is opened.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In Me.Sheets
    sh.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I think using the custom format `@` solved it for me, the `Text` doesn't seem to work w/ch is weird. Also do you know of a way to disable/enable autoformatting function of excel? There used to be one in xl2003

Comment: @forums "custom format @" - it's a symbol for Text format in VBA))

Comment: I tried googling and knew about changing it to text but like my comment above, it keeps being reverted to date. Don't know why `@` worked fine. Thanks for the ms forum link too, learned that autoformatting cannot be simply *turned off* :sigh:

Comment: I feel your pain with excel. My boss just wanted to do everything in excel when I was insisting to use access :sigh again:. Also do you think the reason it reverts to date is because the adjacent cell is in date format?

Comment: can't say for sure about the revert issue, but Excel (and other MS products, for that matter) have been known to be a bit user-unfriendly when trying to "intelligently" do things, like formatting (Excel), indenting (Word), etc.

Comment: Got it, I came across [this](http://superuser.com/a/445421/197515). So that behavior was caused by excel 2010's bad guesswork. It assumes the `DATE` adjacent cell is also a Date. So I did the one in the link and presto, text stayed as text :yey:. I still wish MS stops adding nonsense to excel, or at least give as an easier option to remove it

Comment: well when you think about it, it's not really "bad" guesswork. Most of the data input to Excel, by most users, anywhere, ever, is numeric data of some sort. So it makes sense that when a cell's value **can** be interpreted as numeric, that the application treats it as such until otherwise directed by the user.  So it's really a good guess, 95% of the time. You happen to be using Excel somewhat unconventionally.  Alternatively, you can just insert an apostrophe before you enter the value so it would be like `1-2 and Ecxel will always treat that as string/text and ignore the apostrophe.

Answer (score 4):

1. cut and paste everything into note_pad
2. delete what ever left in xl
3. Select all needed cells, columns row to text format
4. re-paste from note_pad
5. if you need later you can change to date, time formats

Comment: Not happy about having to take the extra step of copy and pasting into notepad then re-pasting into excel. It's the only way my "dashed" entries don't convert to a date. The dashed entries are coming from a java table from an outside source. No other work around has stopped the conversion other than going through the notepad step.

Comment: Another way I use is to put ="1-2" as I have needed the same range info for stuff before - downside is it does not work in calculations...

Answer (score 0):

1. Select all your '.csv' data and copy to notepad
2. Set all cells in new worksheet in Excel to text
3. Paste all your data from Notepad as text
4. Copy the "affected" column back to Notepad
5. Change all your `.` to `,` (e.g. 10.00 to 10,00)
6. Open new Excel book - IMPORTANT
7. Copy your column from Notepad to this new Excel book
8. Copy and paste the column back to your original Excel book

The only drawback is that you have your numbers now with (,) instead of (.).

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

1. save sheet as CSV
2. rename it to `.txt`
3. reopen it in Excel
4. import module is invoked
5. switch from general to text format for each numeric column